# How to resolve url from query into route

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-routing, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to find a way get the symfony 1.4 to render the page:

```
/detail/id/1
```

when url called is:

```
/?url=/detail/id/1
```

Any ideas? Been googling around but so far haven't found the solution for it. Any ideas? I know it could be done with rewrites but i hoped i can do it through routing.yml somehow.

Comment: Hi. Quick answer.. The documentation explains the routing pretty well. You create routes, which you can call with url_for('@my_custom_route') or link_to('Click me', '@my_custom_route') and so on. 

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05 and http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add that line into your routing.yml, in your case I would do (i suppouse that the module is **detail** and the action is **id**):

```
detail_id:
  url:  /?url=/detail/id/:id
  param: { module: detail, action: id }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
```

Getting the **id** from the action with $this->getParameter('id')